# Writing data to a device from user space

Tags: c, linux, x86, linux-device-driver, device-driver

Say I have a memory mapped device attached to my processor, what is the fastest way to write to that device from user-space? What is confusing me is that normally processors employ write-back cache, so when you change some memory location, it does not necessary reflect in the physical memory (mapped to the device in this case). Can some device driver guru explain how this can work?

I am interested in using a user-level device driver for this purpose. And I want the write to be fast, as in the application running on the computer does not need to wait much, just few cycles.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do this would be as follows.

1. Use mmap to map the device address space to user space. The reads and writes from user space then directly go to the device.
2. Setup the mmu to prevent caching. You can also use cache flushing instructions to flush out the cache.